# iOS:appending array of elements from single string to other array

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsarray

i am developing app contains values in dictionary format and am fetching those values in array like below
    note:_detailedarray is an mutable array.

```
[_detailedarray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_firstname ,    
  @"first_name" , _lastname , @"last_name" ,_phoneNumber,@"phone_Number" ,nil]];
    NSArray *ar=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    self.filtereditems=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_detailedarray count]];

    NSLog(@"array is,%@",ar);
    CFRelease(phoneNumbers);

}
  [self.nametxt addTarget:self.autoCompleter action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

_firstnamestring=[_detailedarray valueForKey:@"first_name"]; 

//_firstnamestring is a string and same _lastnamestring and _phnostring///

_lastnamestring=[_detailedarray valueForKey:@"last_name"];
_phonenostring=[_detailedarray valueForKey:@"phone_Number"];
_totalarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_firstnamestring,   
 _lastnamestring, _phonenostring, nil];
```

each string contains  6 values and my problem is how to add the elements from those arrays to one array that means

```
 _ firstnamestring contains 6 values and  _phonenostring cointains 6 values and   
 _lastnamestring contains 6 values how to append the first name,last name and phone 
  no strings at every object at index and keep in single array.
```

Comment: Its better to have a Class and an array that would hold 6 values. Your searching sorting etc will happen to work find without loosing the index.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya he already has a single array with an object for each entry (that object happens to be a dictionary rather than a custom object, but that's not a huge deal). That's what `_detailedArray` is. Don't get me wrong, I think custom objects make more sense, too, but if his question was "how do I get a single array", the answer is "you already had one called `_detailedArray`." I don't quite get this question.

Comment: @Rob: if if get the question correctly, he want to seggregate `firstName` etc... then it would be easy to get them by KVC... `valueForKey:` and everytime he will get in same order and then he can store it in his array(s). Yours view on this?

Comment: In retrospect, I think the `valueForKey` and the three extra arrays was a bit of a red herring. I think he just wanted to get an array of strings in the form of "first last phone", and his attempt was by using `valueForKey`. But there are probably better ways to tackle that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample, it looks like you have an array called `_detailedArray` which is an array of dictionaries that contain three keys, `first_name`, `last_name` and `phone_Number`. When you call `valueForKey` with a particular key on an array of dictionaries, you get an array of the values for that key. That's interesting, but not really useful here.

There are a couple of approaches that I might suggest:

1. If you really need this array of "first last phone" strings, you should build that directly:

   ```
   NSMutableArray *contactStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (NSDictionary *contact in _detailedArray) {
       [contactStrings addObject:[self stringForContact:contact]];
   }
   ```

   Where `stringForContact` might be defined as follows:

   ```
   - (NSString *)stringForContact:(NSDictionary *)contact 
   {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", contact[@"first_name"], contact[@"last_name"], contact[@"phone_Number"]];
   }
   ```

   Clearly, you'd expand this to handle all sorts of scenarios (e.g. no first name, no last name, etc.). But it illustrates the general idea.
2. I must confess that I'm not crazy about the above approach of building an array of strings. First, you're taking up twice the memory for no benefit (e.g. you may only show 20 contacts at a time, but you may have built this whole array for thousands of contacts unnecessarily).

   Also, you now have two arrays that you have to keep synchronized, your `contactStrings` and your `_detailedArray`. If, for example, you add a sorting feature at some future date and you sort `_detailedArray` by last name, you have to now rebuild the `contactStrings` array (and you obviously cannot sort `contactStrings` itself, because it doesn't have the meaningful data about what portion of the string is the first name, and what portion is the last name, etc.)

   I'd personally prefer to stick with `_detailedArray` alone. And then, the presentation of the string representation of the contact becomes a presentation issue, not a duplicative model structure.

   For example, if showing the `_detailedArray` contacts in a table view, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` might look like:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       NSDictionary *contact = _detailedArray[indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = [self stringForContact:contact];

       return cell;
   }
   ```

   So rather than building another array of strings that is largely duplicative of `_detailedArray`, just use `_detailedArray` itself.

Even better, as Anoop Vaidya suggested, I might advise designing your own custom `Contact` class, and replace the array of dictionaries with an array of custom objects. And then you can make the `stringForContact` method an instance method of this model `Contact` class (where it probably belongs), rather coding it right in your view controller.

But hopefully it illustrates the idea: The model should capture the structure of the underlying data, and you can make the string representation of that object a separate method that you call as needed, rather than building a duplicative array of strings.